# xPath help - selecting siblings

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to select the child text of the element "value" for a single "form" that has an ID that matches tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--1.

Here's a sample of my XML

```
<form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement">
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--1</ID>
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">XDAP Type</label>
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Win7 x64 Developer</value>
</form>
<form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement">
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapUser--1</ID>
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">User</label>
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
</form>
<form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement">
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--2</ID>
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">XDAP Type</label>
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Win7 x86 Standard</value>
</form>
```

I was using the xPath `//*[local-name()='form'][*[local-name()='ID'][starts-with(., 'tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--1')]]` but I'm unable to select the value from this query.  In my example, I would like to select the value "Win7 x64 Developer"

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that the XML fragments are part of well-formed XML with a single root element,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement"> 
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--1</ID>  
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">XDAP Type</label>  
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>  
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>  
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Win7 x64 Developer</value> 
  </form>  
  <form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement"> 
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapUser--1</ID>  
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">User</label>  
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>  
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>  
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"/> 
  </form>  
  <form xsi:type="ns1:FormElement"> 
    <ID xsi:type="soapenc:string">tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--2</ID>  
    <label xsi:type="soapenc:string">XDAP Type</label>  
    <labelValue xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>  
    <type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</type>  
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Win7 x86 Standard</value> 
  </form> 
</r>
```

**then this XPath,**

```
string(//form[ID = 'tblXDAP-txtfXdapType--1']/value)
```

**will select the string value of the `value` element of the `form` whose `ID` is as specified,**

```
Win7 x64 Developer
```

**as requested.**